# Type mismatch returning associated trait from generic function in trait

Tags: rust

Why does this code fail to compile? [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=243c7b8182420cc02a3b9edf4ce573ca)

```rust
pub trait Dataset {}

pub trait Property {
    type Value;
    fn value<D: Dataset>(_ds: D) -> Self::Value
    where
        Self: DatasetProperty<D>;
}

pub trait DatasetProperty<D>
where
    Self: Property,
    D: Dataset,
{
}

impl<T> Property for T {
    type Value = String;
    fn value<D: Dataset>(_ds: D) -> Self::Value
    where
        Self: DatasetProperty<D>,
    {
        String::new()
    }
}
```

This errors with:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/lib.rs:23:9
   |
18 |     type Value = String;
   |     -------------------- expected this associated type
19 |     fn value<D: Dataset>(_ds: D) -> Self::Value
   |                                     ----------- expected `<T as Property>::Value` because of return type
...
23 |         String::new()
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected associated type, found struct `std::string::String`
   |
   = note: expected associated type `<T as Property>::Value`
                       found struct `std::string::String`
```

The error points to line 18 where the associated type is set to `String`, but then it's saying `String` was not expected. This code works if I remove the where clause in the `value` function.

Comment: Since `value` requires `Self: DatasetProperty`, and `DatasetProperty` has `Property` as a supertrait, why not move the method to `DatasetProperty`? [example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3515c6e6a96c1e211ffda01684436bcb)

Comment: Is there any specific reason for the `value` function to be in `Property` and not in `DatasetProperty`?

Comment: This was the most I could simplify my actual code to demonstrate the issue. In my real code the Value type requires a GetValue trait that includes a get_value function. And the value function has a default implementation that calls <Value>::get_value(). Then I have properties that implement a different trait where I need to overwrite the value() function.

I've implemented GetValue for String and u64 (and various enums).

This is a workaround because impl<P: Property<Value=String>> Property and impl<P: Property<Value=u64>> results in conflicting implementations.

Comment: I guess that doesn't really answer the question, I probably could move the value function into DatasetProperty with the same logic. But I'd still like to understand why this doesn't work.

Comment: If you want to implement `DatasetProperty<D>` on a type `T`, `T` has to implement `Property`, but if you want to implement `Property` for `T`, `T` has to implement `DatasetProperty`. Is this intended?

Comment: DatasetProperty<D> for T signifies that T is a valid Property for Dataset D. You can implement Property on anything you want, but if you wish to call value() to get the value of that property from D, T must implement DatasetProperty<D>.